# Envoyproxy 1.11 > 1.12 cannot find CORS anymore with RDS

Tags: envoyproxy

I'm currently upgrading our Envoyproxy instances from 1.11 to the latest version supporting V2-api, as for V3-api code changes are required to some of our microservices.

This piece of RDS-config is working for 1.11, but not for 1.12.

```
node:
  id: id_1
  cluster: test

admin:
  access_log_path: "/tmp/admin_access.log"
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

dynamic_resources:
  cds_config:
    api_config_source:
      api_type: GRPC
      grpc_services:
        envoy_grpc:
          cluster_name: ESD_cluster

static_resources:
  secrets:
    - name: server_wildcard_cert
      tls_certificate:
        certificate_chain: { filename: "/etc/envoy/star_2019.crt" }
        private_key: { filename: "/etc/envoy/star_2019.key" }
    - name: validation_context
      validation_context:
        trusted_ca: { filename: "/etc/envoy/cacert.pem" }

  - name: listener_https_internal
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9443 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.file_access_log
            config:
              format: "[%START_TIME%] \"%REQ(:METHOD)% %REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)% %PROTOCOL%\" %RESPONSE_CODE% %RESPONSE_FLAGS% %BYTES_RECEIVED% %BYTES_SENT% %DURAT$
              path: "/dev/stdout"
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: esds_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: backend
              domains:
                - "*"
              routes:
                - match:
                    prefix: "/"
                  route:
                    cluster: ESD_cluster
                    timeout: 120s
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
# static TLS certificate info
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.auth.DownstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificate_sds_secret_configs:
            - name: server_wildcard_cert
            validation_context_sds_secret_config:
              name: validation_context
            alpn_protocols: "h2"

  - name: listener_https
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8443 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.file_access_log
            config:
              format: "[%START_TIME%] \"%REQ(:METHOD)% %REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)% %PROTOCOL%\" %RESPONSE_CODE% %RESPONSE_FLAGS% %BYTES_RECEIVED% %BYTES_SENT% %DURAT$
              path: "/dev/stdout"
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http

          rds:
            route_config_name: ESG_route_configuration
            config_source:
              api_config_source:
                api_type: GRPC
                grpc_services:
                  envoy_grpc:
                    cluster_name: ESD_cluster

              cors:
              allow_origin_string_match:
                - prefix: "*"
              allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
              allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response$
              max_age: "1728000"
              expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message

          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.grpc_web
          - name: envoy.cors
          - name: envoy.router
            config: {}
# static TLS certificate info
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.auth.DownstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificate_sds_secret_configs:
            - name: server_wildcard_cert
            validation_context_sds_secret_config:
              name: validation_context
            alpn_protocols: "h2"

  clusters:
    - name: ESD_cluster
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: STATIC
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    http2_protocol_options: {}
#    tls_context: {}
    upstream_connection_options:
      tcp_keepalive: {}
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: ESD_cluster
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
         - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address: { address: 10.80.1.83, port_value: 5028 }
         - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address: { address: 10.80.1.84, port_value: 5028 }
```

The error message for this:

```
[warning][config] [source/common/protobuf/message_validator_impl.cc:28] Unknown field: type envoy.config.bootstrap.v2.Bootstrap reason INVALID_ARGUMENT:(rds.config_source) cors: Cannot find field.
```

I have been trying to find examples from the Internet about RDS and CORS, but there are none.

Comment: I don't see that the `cors` field is part of the `rds` config in either the v11 or the v12 docs:
- https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.12.0/api-v2/api/v2/core/config_source.proto#envoy-api-msg-core-configsource
- https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.11.0/api-v2/api/v2/core/config_source.proto#envoy-api-msg-core-configsource

are you positive that worked in 1.11?

Comment: @justincely yes, the version is v1.11.2

Comment: Most likely the configuration is not correctly done. Envoyproxy v1.11.2 just accepted it that way. I'm new to envoyproxy, so transforming the configuration to a proper one is challenging for me. The original configuration was done by an other employee.

Comment: I pulled the config you gave here and attempted to put it into a valid bootstrap config and get things to run; no luck.  Can you edit your comment here for the full bootstrap config you used to start up your proxy?  Otherwise, the output of the `/config_dump` endpoint from the admin server would also help to understand.

Comment: @justincely I added the full config to my opening post. Thanks for helping me out!
I already fixed (or tried, as they are not returning errors) deprecated stuff in v1.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

So, as far as I can tell this was something that was never supported, and v11 was just silently dropping the fields where v12 is actually informing you that the field is not supported.  So the real answer to your question is; this was never working, it was just silently not telling you v1.11 but it's informing you in v1.12.

Neither of the API docs have a field `rds.config_source.cors`:

- [v1.11](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.11.0/api-v2/api/v2/core/config_source.proto#envoy-api-msg-core-configsource)
- [v1.12](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.12.0/api-v2/api/v2/core/config_source.proto#envoy-api-msg-core-configsource)

After doing a bit of munging on your config above (there were a few errors, so had to add fields/indent a couple places) I can confirm that `envoy` v11 runs fine but v12 fails for at least some fixes I did.

However, even when running v11, the `cors` field isn't setting anything.  Using the admin endpoint, you can inspect the configuration that's actually set.  For your config, hit `localhost:9901/config_dump` and you'll see there's essentially nothing on your listener:

```
    {
     "listener": {
      "name": "listener_https",
      "address": {
       "socket_address": {
        "address": "0.0.0.0",
        "port_value": 8443
       }
      },
      "filter_chains": [
       {}
      ]
     },
```

This looks to be because your `listener_https` has some additional errors in config.  The only filter you name is the `envoy.file_access_log`, but you attempt to give it a config for the `HttpConnectionManager`, though also at the wrong scope.

I think at this point you need to work out the kinks in the config and make sure from the `config_dump` that the things you attempt to bootstrap really get set even on v1.11.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. I will try to fix all the problems you mentioned. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Could you clarify this a little bit: "You'll see there's essentially nothing on your listener". Did you literally mean nothing, or just cors? In my config_dump i can see all other stuff except cors.